# Datos de una tabla a traves de botones sqlite Android

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

Estoy creando una biblioteca de canciones conectada a una base de datos
Los datos se almacenan en un formulario (titulo, letra, urldelvideo) y se añaden a un listview que solo muestra el titulo y el id.

Al seleccionar el item del listview (en la listview solo muestra el titulo) me manda a una activity con dos botones para seleccionar ver la letra o ver el url del video.

¿Como paso la informacion almacenada a las vistas de cada boton?
He leido que con cursores pero no me funciona.

el en DBHelper tengo este codigo para obtener la letra de la cancion:

```
 public Cursor getLetra(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    String sql = "select Letra from Canciones";
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);


    return c;
}
```

y en la activity donde se mostrará la letra tengo:

```
letra_tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);

    Cursor res = myDb.getLetra();
    String str = "";
    if (res!=null){
        if(res.moveToFirst()){
            str= res.getString(0);
        }
    }
    letra_tv.setText(str);
```

El error que obtengo es:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.inspiron.evidencia2, PID: 18385
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.inspiron.evidencia2/com.example.inspiron.evidencia2.Letra}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor com.example.inspiron.evidencia2.DBHelper.getLetra()' on a null object reference
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3319)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor com.example.inspiron.evidencia2.DBHelper.getLetra()' on a null object reference
                  at com.example.inspiron.evidencia2.Letra.onCreate(Letra.java:28)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: Creo q deberias usar realm para lo de la base de datos , es mas facil tratar los datos como objetos o arrays y no como cursores :D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Estas llamando el método `getLetra()` pero el valor de `myDb` es null:

```
  Cursor res = myDb.getLetra();
```

de acuerdo a tu código me parece que el método getLetra() en realidad obtiene el valor de SQLiteDatabase, por lo tanto llama simplemente el método para obtener un cursor definido por tu Query:

```
  Cursor res = getLetra();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias =)!! Funcionó!

Comment: **CP Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.